# HTML vertically align content of table cell when there's image inside

Tags: html, vertical-alignment, valign

Is there any way to make text vertically be aligned text `Hello World!` to middle of table cell without splitting into two cells?

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td valign="middle" style="vertical-align:middle;">
            Hello World! <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" border="1" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U4Qs4/

Comment: should be on the image or below it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to vertically align the image, not the td element.

Comment: Thanks.

P.S. Its makes no sense why aligning image inside cell will fix cell text alignment... i tried to figure out for years how to do it.

P.P.S. There's no valign property in img tag need to use style="vertical-align:middle;"

Comment: Does not work in Firefox 15, it works in Crome because browser attempts to fix poor coding mistakes :) there's no such property for img source: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp

Comment: as far as I know the image changes the line height, so when you add text to it you need to mention the vertical alignment

Comment: Works for me, i could refer W3 foundation website but their documentation is hard to read. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Works in Chrome FF and IE7 ....

```
<style>
.mid {
    vertical-align:middle
    }
</style>


<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td class="mid">
            <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" class="mid" border="1" />Hello World!
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```